# I am trying to generate random number in textbox when click submit button

Tags: java, jsp, random

```
<form action="#">

<%
Random random=new Random();
int num=random.nextInt();
%>

Random Number:<input type="text" value="<%=num %>"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="RandomNumberGenerator"/>
</form>
```

When page is reload random number is generate in textbox.but when i click RandomNumberGenerator `button` it can not generate random number.How to generate random number when i click RandomNumberGenerator `Button`.

Comment: Do you need to generate random number in java or JS is also possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want some action to happen only in the browser then use JavaScript.
Here is an example:

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input'),
      btn = document.querySelector('button');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var MIN = 1, MAX = 50;
  input.value = Math.floor(Math.random() * (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN;
});
```

```html
<input type='text' name="some" value='15' />
<br/><br/>
<button>Get new number</button>
```

`button` to be click-able it must have a click event listener, which will generate the random number and assign it to the input.

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help.

Comment: is possible in java or not.if possible how it work give me idea

Comment: Java runs on the server, so if you want to use Java then define a microService that will generate a random number and call it from the page by AJAX. So yes, it is possible but more expensive and not practical.